# Escaping double quotes in form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery to append options in a dropdown menu, which accesses the database to output the information as the value for each option. Some of the results in the database store inches (") and therefore when appending the value of the option, the value tag is closed of early.
The dropdown options are used in a form, therefore when using $_POST to retrieve the value from the option, a string that's cut off prematurely is shown.

The following code I have used to add a backslash to escape the double quotes but that doesn't seem the help:

```
.append('<option value="' + (data['GmWt_Desc1'].substr(data['GmWt_Desc1'].indexOf(' ')+1)).replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '">' + data['GmWt_Desc1'].substr(data['GmWt_Desc1'].indexOf(' ')+1) + '</option>')
.val(data['GmWt_Desc1'])
```

The alteration in html:

```
<option value="pat,  (1\" sq,="" 1="" 3\"="" high)"="">pat,  (1" sq, 1/3" high)</option>
```

When retrieving with $_POST, the following is given:
Array
(
    [0] => pat,  (1\
)
What I'm trying to retrieve with $_POST:

```
pat,  (1" sq, 1/3" high
```

How do I go about retrieving the whole description?

Comment: Maybe you could replace the " with ' ... it could be a simple workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use jQuery's inbuilt functions to set the attributes. They will escape the text correctly.

```js
var data = 'pat,  (1" sq, 1/3" high';

// create an option and set its attributes
$("<option></option>").appendTo("#mySelect").text(data).val(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
</select>
```

Comment: I thought I was already doing this with .val(data['GmWt_Desc1']), data['GmWt_Desc1'] containing the description: "pat,  (1" sq, 1/3" high')"?

Comment: In you question you have `'<option value="' + (data['GmWt_Desc1']..`

Comment: And the `.val()` part will apply it to the `select`, not the `option` as you were intending. In other words, `$(mySelect).append('<option value="' + data + '"</option>').val(moreData)` will try to put `moreData` onto the `select`, and not the `option`

Comment: My pleasure. That is why I chose to use `appendTo` rather than `append` in my answer